# Display Ad type per level?

Tags: firebase, events, google-bigquery

I'm starting to use BigQuery for work so I'm very new to it, and I'm struggling with a request.

So I request data from a mobile game from Firebase. I would like to get the number of types of ads watched per level. For instance: 
Type of ads (Inter/Rewarded) - Number of ads watched - level number

I started with this:

```
SELECT
  param.value.string_value AS Type_of_ads,
  COUNT(param.value.string_value) AS Nber
FROM
  `*Name of the project**`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param
WHERE
event_name = 'Fullscreen_displayed'
  AND param.key = 'Ad_type'
  AND user_first_touch_timestamp > 1560587334000000 #15/06/2019
GROUP BY
  param.value.string_value
ORDER BY
  param.value.string_value
```

With this, I only have the number of ads and ad_type in total. I would like to have per level. So I did this:

```
SELECT
  param.value.string_value AS Type_of_ads,
  COUNT(param.value.string_value) AS Nber,
  app_info.version AS Version,
  COUNT (event_name) AS Runs
FROM
  `Name of the project*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param2
WHERE
event_name = 'Fullscreen_displayed'
  AND param.key = 'Ad_type'
  AND event_name = 'Level_end'
  AND param2.key = 'Level'
GROUP BY
  Type_of_ads, Version
ORDER BY
  Type_of_ads, Version, Runs
```

But I have the "This query didn't return any result". I can't figure out how to fix it. Could you help me on this matter please? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: An event cannot be both Fullscreen_displayed and Level_end at the same time. It's actually a similar question to your previous one. 
Also, you're scanning full event table, which is costly. I'd recommend you to split them to separate event tables. You can reach me by searching my name in Google for more details.

Comment: Are you sure you need to unnest the same field twice?   UNNEST(event_params) AS param,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param2

Comment: Mh if I don't UNNEST param 1 and param 2 I get an error

Comment: Which error? Can yo update your question showing more details?